# How can I filter based on unique taxonomy term values?

Tags: 8, views, entities, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type "book". One of its field "field_language" referencing to "language" taxonomy term. field_language can have only one value.

Consider this is the content I Have,

[image]

**I want, a single book for every unique taxonomy item of "language" taxonomy term.**

I want the view to generate a result like this,

[image]

How can I implement this using views?

Needs Help!

Thanks

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions; if you have more information to add, just edit the original. Thanks!

Comment: Don't you mean you want to list all books under C++ in the same row, not just skip them (Book 2, 7 10)?

Comment: @Kevin No, I want only one book and latest one for each taxonomy term value

Comment: @Kevin Select distinct, tick off 'reduce duplicates' in the relationship, and aggregate the query so you can group by term name.  could you explain this in detail.